# How to draw a text in canvas in android

Tags: android, text, android-canvas

I am writing an application that consists of a gauge view. I downloaded from [here](https://github.com/CodeAndMagic/GaugeView) and i want to draw text inside the gauge view (that is at the center of the gauge view) how can i draw a text inside a gauge view please help me.

After my friends answers in stack overflow i did it like this but it did not works please make it work

```
 private void drawGauge() 
    {
        if (null != mBackground) 
        {
           mBackground.recycle();
        }

        /*--For Semi circle put getHeight()/2--*/
        mBackground = Bitmap.createBitmap(getWidth(), getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        newBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(mBackground.getWidth(), mBackground.getHeight(), Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas newCanvas = new Canvas(newBitmap);
        final Canvas canvas = new Canvas(mBackground);
        final float scale = Math.min(getWidth(), getHeight());
        canvas.scale(scale, scale);
        canvas.translate((scale == getHeight()) ? ((getWidth() - scale) / 2) / scale : 0,(scale == getWidth()) ? ((getHeight() - scale) / 2) / scale : 0);

        Paint paintText = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        paintText.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        paintText.setTextSize(50);
        paintText.setTextAlign(Align.CENTER);
        paintText.setStyle(Style.FILL);
        Rect rectText = new Rect();
        paintText.getTextBounds(captionString, 0, captionString.length(), rectText);
        newCanvas.drawText(captionString, 0, rectText.height(), paintText);


        //canvas.drawText("MedeQuip", 200, 500, shadowpaint);
        //drawRim(canvas);
        //drawFace(canvas);
```

For vipluv:

```
 protected void onDraw(final Canvas canvas) {
        drawBackground(canvas);
        final float scale = Math.min(getWidth(), getHeight());
        canvas.scale(scale, scale);
        canvas.translate((scale == getHeight()) ? ((getWidth() - scale) / 2) / scale : 0, (scale == getWidth()) ? ((getHeight() - scale) / 2) / scale : 0);

        if (mShowNeedle) {
            drawNeedle(canvas);
        }

        if (mShowText) {
            drawText(canvas);
        }

        Paint paintText = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        paintText.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        paintText.setTextSize(150);
        paintText.setTextAlign(Align.CENTER);
        paintText.setStyle(Style.FILL);
        Rect rectText = new Rect();
        paintText.getTextBounds(captionString, 0, captionString.length(), rectText);
        canvas.drawText(captionString, rectText.width(), rectText.height(), paintText);

        computeCurrentValue();
    }
```

Comment: canvas.drawText() should do it.

Comment: This would be a good reference : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pCUQ_6iA_3o

Comment: i did  it dude but not works  @vipluv

Answer (score 0):

In the onDraw() function in their GaugeView.java file, add a canvas.drawText() just before the call to computeCurrentValue().

Use your own Paint object, and make sure you have initialized its textsize and color properties.

Comment: again not working dude  i did it as you say @vipluv

Comment: are you sure you have set textsize correctly? in my experience, the text is drawn sometimes but is too small to be seen.

Comment: i set the text size to 50 dude @vipluv

Comment: you need to add the drawText() in the onDraw() function, @lakshman. Not in the drawGauge() function.

Comment: Here check out the code i did after onDraw() but it didn't work for me buddy